# Get Id of inserted Document nodejs and mangodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I try to insert from `nodejs` to `mangodb` , I was able to insert document into the database , but I don't know how to get the ID , can I get the ID when the inserted success ?

This is insert.js

```
const Video = require("../models/Video");

Video.findOne({ title }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ message: { msgBody: "Error hac occured", msgError: true } });
    }
    if (user) {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: { msgBody: "Title is already taken", msgError: true },
      });
    } else {
      const newvideo = new Video({ title, singer, country, genre });
      newvideo.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({
            message: { msgBody: "Error has occured", msgError: true },
          });
        } else {
          res.status(201).json({
            message: { msgBody: "Add success", msgError: false }, 
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

This is Video.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const VideoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  singer: {
    type: String,
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  genre: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("video", VideoSchema);
```

Hope you guys understand what I'm asking :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save method also provides a response in the callback. Please check the following code :

```
newvideo.save((err, video) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json({
            message: { msgBody: "Error has occured", msgError: true },
          });
        } else {
          //get the id of inserted video
          let videoId = video._id;

          res.status(201).json({
            message: { msgBody: "Add success", msgError: false }, 
          });
        }
      });
```